# Can't export XML for each products

Tags: php, xml

That is my [view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0PiN.jpg)

My code:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");

$dateAdded = $xml->createElement("DATE_ADDED", date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$dateAdded = $xml->appendChild($dateAdded);

$shop = $xml->createElement("SHOP");
$shop = $xml->appendChild($shop);

foreach ($post as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $shopproduct = $xml->createElement("SHOPPRODUCT");
        $test = $xml->createElement($key, $product[$key]);
        $test = $shopproduct->appendChild($test);
        $shopproduct = $shop->appendChild($shopproduct);
    }
}

$xml->save('test.xml');
```

Variable `$post` looks like this:

```
array(2) {
  ["product_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["name"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

Variable `$products` looks like this:

```
array(2 {
    [0] =>
    array(2) {
        ["product_id"] =>
        string(2) "30"
        ["name"] =>
        string(12) "Canon EOS 5D"
    }
    [1] =>
    array(2) {
            ["product_id"] =>
            string(2) "47"
            ["name"]=>
            string(9) "HP LP3065"
        }
}
```

The result from code, an XML file, looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATE_ADDED>2017-06-26 11:52:59</DATE_ADDED>
<SHOP>
    <SHOPPRODUCT>
        <product_id>30</product_id>
    </SHOPPRODUCT>
    <SHOPPRODUCT>
        <product_id>47</product_id>
    </SHOPPRODUCT>
    <SHOPPRODUCT>
        <name>Canon EOS 5D</name>
    </SHOPPRODUCT>
    <SHOPPRODUCT>
        <name>HP LP3065</name>
    </SHOPPRODUCT>
</SHOP>
```

How to make it to looks like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATE_ADDED>2017-06-26 11:52:59</DATE_ADDED>
<SHOP>
    <SHOPPRODUCT>
        <product_id>30</product_id>
        <name>Canon EOS 5D</name>
    </SHOPPRODUCT>
    <SHOPPRODUCT>
        <product_id>47</product_id>
        <name>HP LP3065</name>
    </SHOPPRODUCT>
</SHOP>
```

Comment: The intended output is not valid XML because it has two root notes.

Comment: if i push date_added in <SHOP> ? @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: If `<SHOP>` is the only root node and there aren't other errors then it should indeed be valid XML. Whatever, you'll notice invalid XML as soon as you want to use it, when the XML parser fails.

Comment: Fix it and check it with online xml validator, but have another error with this row:

        <description>&lt;div&gt;&#13;
            Just when you thought iMac had everything, now there&acute;s even more. More powerful Intel Core 2 Duo processors. And more memory standard. Combine this with Mac OS X Leopard and iLife &acute;08, and it&acute;s more all-in-one than ever. iMac packs amazing performance into a stunningly slim space.&lt;/div&gt;&#13;
        </description>


The entity "acute" was referenced, but not declared.
Description comes from DB

Comment: `&` is a special char in XML and needs to be escaped, either by surrounding the complete tag content in a CDATA block or by encoding it as `&amp;`. `DOMDocument` should take care of this automatically but, anyway, question comments are not a good place to ask new questions.

Comment: Yeah, i know :) thank u anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your variables, you should iterate over `$products` first and `$post` second:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $shopproduct = $xml->createElement("SHOPPRODUCT");
    foreach ($post as $key => $value) {
        $test = $xml->createElement($key, $product[$key]);
        $test = $shopproduct->appendChild($test);
        $shopproduct = $shop->appendChild($shopproduct);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah .. that's it .... i am feel like an idiot, but i'm newbie :) THANK U !